# Delayed image capturing

Tags: android, android-intent, camera

I know that is easy to fire an intent for image capturing and then after the user press on the capture button to take the image location of the image...

But I want to do something like this:
-user press a button
-camera app is started
-after 10seconds the image is taken automatically (no user interaction needed)

Answer (score 0):

i think for your custom use case, you could write your own camera activity and then capture at 10 seconds

Edit: you can use this tutorial http://code.google.com/p/openmobster/wiki/CameraTutorial

Also the camera preview is present in apidemos application. It is present at Graphics->CameraPreview.

Comment: can you give me little more details how can I do this ?, thanks

Answer (score 0):

hmmm, maybe have a handler with a counter updating a TextView every second (So the app isnt seen as frozen) and then once the counter has reached ten take the photo

---

```
    int counter2 = 0;

    private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask2 = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            if (counter2 == 10){

                takepicture();
            }
            counter2++;

            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
     };
```

Comment: My question is how can I take photo after 10 second ?, for example I press a button and after 10 second the image is captured